# .js file modification not working with ocmod opencart

Tags: javascript, php, opencart, ocmod

```
<file path="catalog/view/javascript/common.js">
<operation>
  <search><![CDATA['add': function(product_id, quantity) {]]></search>
  <add position="replace">
    <![CDATA['add': function(product_id, m, quantity) {
        alert('ok');
        quantity = m*quantity;
    ]]>
  </add>
</operation>
```

This is my xml also I do not get error in ocmod.log, please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't modify client side files with ocmod or vqmod:

> css & js files - These files are rendered at the browser level, not at
>   the server level, so vQmod has no effect on these. You can, however,
>   create new files and use vQmod to alter the tpl files to point to
>   these new css/js files. Or you can put `<style>` and `<script>` tags
>   directly into the tpl file using vQmod.

About vQmod:
https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki/About-vQmod